# Phonegap SQLite id unique is null

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm not sure that I'm getting an id primary key in my sqlite table.

When I create my table I use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HABITS (id unique, uid, text, orglvl, habitstatus)
```

The other properties are fine, and I can retrieve `results.rows.item(i).text`, but `results.rows.item(i).id` is `NULL`

Also upon Insert, when I try to get `results.insertId`, I get an error of "undefined", which started this whole wondering for me.

What am I doing wrong - how come I have no id's when I have created them in my table?

Comment: How are you inserting them into your table? Your ID isn't an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, so it won't be filled automatically.

Comment: You need to provide more information as suggested by @Colonel. You could use the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword definition e.g `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT` for id column, so you do not have to insert any values for id.

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` usually isn't neccessary when using SQLite. See http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 0):

To get an [autoincrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you must use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.